# Non-terminating Java program

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have this Java input-related problem.
I'm solving some cases in UVAToolkit, but there are some problems that the line input requires from the *System.in*. Basing from these codes below, how could I terminate the problem once I've pressed  key? The sample input/output are displayed below.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String line;
while((line = scanner.nextLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
System.out.println("done");
```

Sample Input:

```
1 10
10 100
100 1000
```

Sample Output:

```
1 10
10 100
100 1000
done
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't check for null input but for an empty string. This way, you should be able to terminate just by pressing the return key.

```
while(!(line = scanner.nextLine()).equals(""))
```

Comment: You will need to check for null anyway, unless you want to deal with [`NoSuchElementException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) or NullPointerException!

Comment: Shouldn't happen in the case when you are reading from System.in.

Answer (score 1):

To end the input, you should pree <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, otherwise, `scanner.nextLine()` will not return null, but hang.

if you want to quit the application once the word `quit` entered for example, you can do:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String line;
while((line = scanner.nextLine()) != null && !line.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
System.out.println("done");
```

Comment: Or check for the empty String "" instead of null

Answer (score 1):

Either use sentinel value like `STOP\n` or close the stream. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>z</kbd> for windows(i guess) and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> for Linux to close the stream.

Comment: The judge would like the program to terminate upon pasting only the input and an optional <enter> key is required to run the program and terminate it within the given time

Answer (score 0):

You could decide on a special string that will make the loop end, and check for this special string. For example:

```
while((line = scanner.nextLine()) != null) {
    if (line.equals("quit") break;
    System.out.println(line);
}
System.out.println("done");
```

Comment: There is no such "quit" in the sample input

Comment: Hence the usefulness as a terminator for the input :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for an empty line instead of null:

```
while((line = scanner.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: You should check for `!...isEmpty()`.