# Non-terminating Java program 2

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I have the same problem as before posted in this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062749/non-terminating-java-program).
I don't why but when I tried it again but this time using Eclipse (I used Netbeans in the link). I get this results which is strictly wrong. In UVAToolkit, ever misleading white-space could return a wrong answer.

If by any chance, should I use BufferedReader instead?

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Code [Note: located in the main(String[] args) method]

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String line;
while(!(line = scanner.nextLine()).equals("")) {
     System.out.println(line);
}
System.out.println("done");
```

Case Input: [No white-space at the end of "1000" string]

```
1 10
1 100
1 1000
```

Case Output [Note: "new-line" pertains to a white-space enter ]

```
1 10
1 100
"new-line"
1 1000
"new-line"
done
"new-line"
```

Correct Case Output [Note: No white-space at the end of the "done" string]

```
1 10
1 100
1 1000
done
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-terminating Java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062749/non-terminating-java-program) - You accepted a poor answer the first time; the other answers are correct.

Comment: *System.out.println(line);* will end *every* line with a "new-line".

Comment: BrianRoach, which answer would be the correct one? I've tried most of them yet all returned the same outputcomments may only be edited for 5 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will display the result string of input if it is not an empty string and display "done" when it is done.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ReadConsoleScanner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean stop = false;
        BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String sWhatever = "";
        try {
            while(!(stop = (sWhatever = bufferRead.readLine()).matches(""))){
                if (!stop) System.out.println(sWhatever);
            }
            System.out.println("done");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Regarding your expectation below:

> Case Input: [No white-space at the end of "1000" string]

I think it is quite difficult to find a way to avoid whitespace (empty string) which is needed as the sentinel to the loop, unless the final input is expected to be "1 1000" where we can change the sentinel of the loop as follows:

```
while(!(stop = (sWhatever = bufferRead.readLine()).contains("1 1000"))){
    //whatever
}
```

Comment: Strange when I change the input from console to a file via FileReader, the correct output displays properply. I agree to you that it is difficult to avoid the whitespaces, args.